# Parámetro en Query Object

Tags: sql, genexus

**GX17u2
C#**

Necesito pasar 3 parámetros en un query object para obtener una gráfica de barras. Una numérica EmpresaId, y 2 fechas FechaIni y FechaFin

```
&EmpresaId=1
&FechaFin=&Today
&FechaIni=&Today.AddDays(-7)
QueryViewer1.Object=VisitasPorFecha(&EmpresaId,&FechaIni,&FechaFin)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
========== SQL statement generation started ==========
Generating QueryVisitas ...
error spc0009: Type mismatch in condition: AuditFch >= &@FechaIni@. (Procedure 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest' Source, Line: 2, Details)
warning spc0047: Variable @EmpresaId@ not defined; N(10.2) assumed. (Procedure 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest', Details)
warning spc0047: Variable @FechaIni@ not defined; N(10.2) assumed. (Procedure 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest', Details)
warning spc0047: Variable @FechaFin@ not defined; N(10.2) assumed. (Procedure 'GeneXus.Common.GoogleDirectionsServiceRequest', Details)
Failed: SQL statement generation
error: Type mismatch in condition: AuditFch >= &@FechaIni@. (Query 'QueryVisitas', Structure)
```

No se da cuenta que son Date y cree que son Numeric. O estoy haciendo algo mal o quizá sea un bug.

¿Alguien con algún ejemplo de como pasar parámetros en query objects?

Answer (score 1):

como estas?

Es raro que hayas llegado a ese estado, porque el IDE te da un error si los tipos de datos a comparar no son compatibles.

De cualquier forma, lo que podes hacer para resolver el problema es declarar los tipos vos de forma manual.
Eso lo logras posicionandote sobre cada uno de los parametros y en las propiedades (F4) le asignas el tipo que vos quieras.

Con eso vas a poder resolver.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu recomendación, lo hice y seguía con el mismo error. Luego, cree un nuevo objeto query exactamente igual y funcionó. Esa inestabilidad al hacer algo es muy extraña y hace perder un tiempo valioso. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Probaste con este codigo:

```
&Parameters.Clear()

&Parameter.Name = "ParametroId"
&Parameter.Value = !"1"
&Parameters.Add(&Parameter)
```

Saludos

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Gracias GXSG, lo que pasa que fallaba el objeto query, no al pasarle los parámetros.